# Files in the same directory coming from two different branches

Tags: svn

In my checkout from Subversion I've got a file with some unexpected content.

When I do an `svn info` on that file, I see that both the URL and Relative URL says it's coming from a completely different branch from the branch I think I'm working on. The other files in the same folder give the expected branch.

If the whole directory was consistently pointing at a different branch from the other directories then this would be a typical mixed revision scenario and I could simply check out the directory again from the correct branch. But I don't think that applies down at the file level.

I've tried deleting the directory and doing a `svn up` from the root; the directory is recreated but it still has files coming from two different branches.

What could be causing this and how can I fix it? I just want to get back to the state where all the files are coming from the same branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did an `svn switch` of the directory to the correct branch a few of the files got changed including the one I was having problems with. After that, `svn info` showed the correct thing.

So it looks like something went wrong part way through an earlier switch (perhaps conflicts that I didn't resolve properly) and redoing the switch at this level mopped up the mess.

I guess the switch state is stored inside the `.svn` directory, which is why deleting the directory and doing `svn up` from the root wasn't enough to fix it.